# Click event is working while running script directly in browser but its not working when same UI is being accessed in popup windows

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Web elements is working fine when accessing a specific URL directly in an actual windows using selenium and I'm able to perform action on those elements, but when same code is being executed for the same URL after login into the system to perform action (this time same screen open in popup windows (modal dialog)) and selenium commands like (click) not working and no exception or error message appearing on console.

Case#1: Accessing URL directly using actual browser and performing click action:
[Please refer to UI in this case#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d8ug.png)

```
driver.switchTo().frame("myframe");
        if(driver.findElement(nextButton).isDisplayed()) {      
            driver.findElement(nextButton).click();
            System.out.println("Next button enabled on Clicked");   
        } else {
            System.out.println("Next button NOT Clicked");
        }
```

Console result: Next Button Clicked 
Actual Result: Action performed on UI)

Case#2: Accessing same URL after login into system and as per system functionality same URL will open in model windows and then performing click action:
[Please refer to UI in case#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4hzk.jpg)

```
driver.switchTo().frame("myframe");
        if(driver.findElement(nextButton).isDisplayed()) {      
            driver.findElement(nextButton).click();
            System.out.println("Next button enabled on Clicked");   
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tool button enabled But NOT Clicked");
        }
```

Console result: Next Button Clicked 
Actual Result action NOT being performed on UI) :-(

Here is HTML Code where element ID is appearing:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <html>
                <body>
                <.......Some other elemets defined here......>

                <div id="nextButton" title="Next (N)" class="playerSp next-button" hoverstyle="next-button-over" clickevent="nextButton" keycode="78" tabindex="2" style="display: block; background-image: url(&quot;../../../common_core/media/images/orange_skin/orange_sprite.png&quot;);"></div>

                <.......Some other elemets defined here......>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case #2, where are you switching to the new window?!?!

Comment: Before posting code, please take a minute to make sure it's properly formatted. Improperly indented code (among other formatting issues) make it hard to read and will make it less likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean modal window or an actual new browser window when you say "popup window," but if the same button exists on the "base" window as well as the "popup" window, quite likely Selenium is clicking the button on the base window instead of the popup window.

If the "popup window" is a modal dialog, then you need to make sure your element locator is returning a unique element when the popup is open. If the locator matches multiple elements, Selenium will only operate on the first one matched.

If the "popup window" is an actual new browser window, you need to be able to switch focus to that window. This can be tricky if the new window has no window ID. This space is too small to get into explaining how to do that :) but you should be able to look it up.

Comment: Hi Tyler, Thanks for your time. I have provided some more information and edited my question, may this time my question is more clear to you. Further more after login into the system the UI screen appears in only model window and not on actual window. Please let me know if you require more information further.

Comment: I have already cross verified element Id and it is appearing only one time, xPath has been also used in place of ID, but result remain same.

Comment: Where are you verifying the action has been performed? You could have an issue with those locators, such as where they might differ between in-browser and "popup" conditions.